# Populating a self join table in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a product table and a related product table, related works one way:

```
Product(id: int, name: string)
RelatedProduct(id: int, product1: int, product2: int)
```

With the following models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :uniqueness => true, :presence => true
  has_many :relations, :class_name => "RelatedProducts", :foreign_key => :product1, inverse_of: :source
  has_many :related_products, through: :relations, :source => :destination
end

class RelatedProducts < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :source, :class_name => "Product", inverse_of: :relations
  belongs_to :destination, :foreign_key => :product2, :class_name => "Product"
end
```

This works if I prepopulate the RelatedProducts table, the show view will correctly display all the related products. What I cannot figure out is how do to populate RelatedProducts from the html?

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="related-products field">
    <h3>Related Products</h3>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :related_products, Product.where.not(id: @product.id), :self, :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Update Products' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The strong parameters are defined as:

```
params.require(:product).permit(:name, related_products: [:id, :name])
```

Comment: Maybe trying making a form_for for the related_products model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to make the view use the ids and then submit them

```
<div class="related-products field">
  <h3>Related Products</h3>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :related_products, Product.where.not(id: @product.id), :id, :name %>
</div>
```

I then coupled this with a function in the model to convert the id list to a list of products

```
def related_products_list=(ids)
  self.related_products = ids.reject(&:empty?).collect { |id| Product.find(id) }
end
```

This worked for submitting but the checkboxes would not be pre checked on edits. This was because the model talks about products but the view has a list of ids so would not spot matches. The solution I used was to manually loop through the collection to create the checkboxes instead of using collection_check_boxes.

```
<% Product.where.not(id: @product.id).each do |p| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'product[related_products][]', p.id, @product.is_related_to?(p), id: "product_related_products_" + p.id.to_s %>
  <%= label_tag "product_related_products_" + p.id.to_s, p.name %>
<% end %>
```